# JSON parsing not giving correct values using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Hi I tried to parse a JSON like:

```
{"error":{"code":20,"message":"Transaction not found."}}
```

The Code is used is :

```
GulfBoxError errordetails= new Gson().fromJson(json, GulfBoxError.class);
                System.out.println("RESULT   :"+errordetails.getCode()+"   "+errordetails.getMessage());
```

Class file is:

```
public class GulfBoxError {
public int code;
public String message;

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
}
```

Every time i tries and i didn't get he value here:

```
RESULT   :0   null
```

Any Idea Why?? What i am missing here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parse error using gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915141/json-parse-error-using-gson)

Comment: @ErikKralj What error property?

Comment: @Balasubramanian. This is not duplicate! Question may seems duplicate but its actually different!

Comment: there is a mismatch between your Object definition and the JSON - the Object you've defined is nested under `"error"` in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need getters if you don't encapsulate fields.
- You object is mailformed. Top level should contain only one field: `error`.

The code should look like:

```
public class GufError{
    public GulfBoxError error;
}

public class GulfBoxError {
    public int code;
    public String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

```
GufError errordetails= new Gson().fromJson(json, GufError.class);
```

Comment: Why is it doing like this! I used the above method many times and was successfully! This happens only in this case

Comment: Yes! Silly mistake! Let me check that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, In case you don't want to create a separate class as wrapper:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObj = gson.fromJson(json,JsonObject.class);
GulfBoxError errordetails= gson.fromJson(jsonObj.get("error"), GulfBoxError.class);
System.out.println("RESULT   :"+errordetails.getCode()+"   "+errordetails.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GulfBoxError class isn't correct.

You need something like this:

```
 public class GulfError{
    public GulfBoxError error;
}

 class GulfBoxError {
    public int code;
    public String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

And parse it in this way:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String filename="/...Pathtoyour/json.json";
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
    GulfError errordetails= gson.fromJson(reader, GulfError.class);
    System.out.print("errordetails: " + gson.toJson(errordetails));
```

Anyway, if you want to use your GulfBoxError class, you could do this:

```
      Type listType = new TypeToken<Map<String, GulfBoxError>>(){}.getType();
      Map<String, GulfBoxError> mapGulfBoxError= gson.fromJson(reader,listType);
      for (Map.Entry<String, GulfBoxError> entry : mapGulfBoxError.entrySet())
      {
          System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + "\nValue:" + gson.toJson(entry.getValue()));

      }
```

Sometimes this could be useful if you don't want to create exactly the object that represent your Json.